# How to use react-router useNavigate to replace params the way we did in v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my app currently on React-Router v5, we have a redirect link from an email that includes a `"referrer=email"` param that we use to determine some initial state on the login/signup pages:

```js
const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams(search);
const referrer = queryParameters.get('referrer');
const [open, setOpen] = useState(
  pathname === '/signup' && referrer !== 'email' ? false : true
);
```

However after we have made that determination, we want to strip the `"referrer"` param from the URL search string which we are currently doing with `history.replace`. However, the docs for the migration to v6 and `useNavigate` do not seem to factor in this use case of the `replace` functionality:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // remove params from URL
  history.replace({
    referrer: '',
  });
}, []);
```

Is there an option with the new navigate API that would map to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`options.replace`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate#optionsreplace) for the details how to issue a RELACE action instead of a PUSH action, similar to `history.replace`.

If you just want to update the URL search params then use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook. It works just like the `useNavigate` hook but works on the queryString, e.g. the search params.

Example:

```js
import { useMatch, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const isSignup = useMatch("/signup");
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

const [open, setOpen] = useState(() => {
  const referrer = searchParams.get("referrer");
  return isSignup && referrer === 'email';
});

useEffect(() => {
  setSearchParams(searchParams => {
    // remove the "referrer" from the queryString
    searchParams.delete("referrer");

    // return the next queryString
    return searchParams;
  }, { replace: true }); // <-- redirect action
}, []);
```

Example using `useNavigate` if this is the hook you really want to use:

```js
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();
const { pathname, search } = useLocation();
const searchParams = React.useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);

const [open, setOpen] = useState(() => {
  const referrer = searchParams.get("referrer");
  return pathname === '/signup' && referrer === 'email';
});

useEffect(() => {
  // remove the "referrer" from the queryString
  searchParams.delete("referrer");

  // redirect to the current path with the update queryString
  navigate({
    pathname: ".",
    search: searchString.toString(),
  }, { replace: true });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
//snip...

useEffect(() => {
  const url = ...;
  navigate(url);

}[])
```

[source](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).